# Java 8 lambda scope example from leanpub

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to read through this https://leanpub.com/whatsnewinjava8/read#leanpub-auto-scope and I'm a bit confused as to:

1. why toString() is called in r1's assignment
2. how this demonstrates the scope available to the lambda

Comment: Please create a self-contained answer. Copy&Paste the relevant parts over to here. Otherwise, if the link becomes invalid, your question is kind of worthless and does not help others anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer the first question with certainty:

When you call the function `System.out.println`, it will do the following:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at
>   first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-

And the subsequent call of `String.valueOf(x)` will do the following:

> If the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the
>   value of obj.toString() is returned.

Source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-

Since `this` refers to an instance of `Hello` it will just call the `Hello.toString()` method on the given instance - callstack:

```
System.out.println(this);
String.valueOf(this);
this.toString();
```

The second question regarding the scope probably means that you can still refer to the methods and fields of the enclosing class, yet I find this example a weird and also not very well documented one.

Answer (score 0):

In a lamdba, this refers to the class declaring the lambda, unlike an anonymous class where this this refers to the anonymous class.

For exemple :

```
 public class Hello {
    Runnable r1 = () -> out.println(this);
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            out.println(this);
        }
    };

    public String toString() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Hello().r1.run(); // Hello, world!
        new Hello().r2.run(); // something like Hello$1@776ec8df
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you define a `toString` method in a class:

```
class ArbitaryClass {
     String toString() { System.out.println("Object of ArbitaryClass."); }
}
```

Then when you call `System.out.println` on an instance of it, `toString` method will be triggered:

```
System.out.println(new ArbitaryClass()); // Will print Object of ArbitaryClass.
```

So here when you are trying to run `new Hello().r1.run()`, it's just invoking `out.println(this)` which is, (**this**), a representation of the current object, (**new Hello()**), of class which in turn will invoke `toString` method and print the *"Hello, world!"* message.

And as long as you call `out.println(this)` or `out.println(toString())` inside the class then lambda has access to its properties and methods.